# Is it possible to pass string with intent without changing Activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I wonder if it is possible to pass string with intent to another Activity without opening that activity.

I am making Android app with 3 layouts and 3 Activities. Firt is MainActivity which is main screen. Then i have SettingsActivity and  URLClickActivity. I start app with MainActivity then i must go to SettingsActivity and type in EditText my web adress. Then i go back to MainActivity and then to URLClickActivity. I tried to pass string url_adress directly from Settings to UrlClick.

```
     Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, URLClickActivity.class);
     i.putExtra("int_adress", adress);
     startActivity(i);
```

I tried with this code but when i run in it closes the Settings and open URLClick Activity.

Is it possible to do it somehow to direcly pass string from SettingsActivity to URLClick Activity or i must first pass string to MainActivity and then to URLClickActivity.?

Comment: It is possible. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible.
But to achieve what you are explaining, you should use the [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method.
Here is the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) to help you implement this method.

Here is [another implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/3615879).

Answer (score 0):

As Simon said that its not possible.

- Instead of using extras in Intent, you can also [save the URL in `SharedPreference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) in your `SettingsActivity` and then retrieve it in your `URLClickActivity` directly.
- Otherwise you can use `startActivityForResult` as Simon suggested. Retrieve the url back to MainActivity and then start the `URLClickActivity` with the url as extra.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to, is storing a persisted value for another Activity to consume and/or  read. To do this you could store it into SharedPreferences and then read that preference in the UrlActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using my way -

First create this method in URLClickActivity.class -

```
public void uRL(String url){

    String vURL = url;
    //vURL is a local variable which will store the url passed from SettingsActivity

}
```

Now in SettingsActivity, add this code -

```
URLClickActivity urlActivity = new URLClickActivity();
urlActivity.uRL(adress);
```

Once you call the method from above code, you will have address stored in vURL.